# Какая разница между "почему" и "зачем"?

Tags: грамматика

Какая разница между "почему" и "зачем"?

Answer (score 5):

*Почему* means "for what reason", *зачем* means "for what purpose".

The latter assumes a purposeful action by a sentient subject, and asks about the goal of this action.

*Почему ты говоришь по-русски?* and *зачем ты говоришь по-русски?* both translate as "why are you speaking Russian?". But a valid answer to the former could be "because I was born in a Russian-speaking family", and to the latter "because people around me only understand Russian".

The former is asking "how come you're speaking Russian?", and the latter "for what purpose are you speaking Russian?".

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at their difference from a psychological point of view.

1. The question "Зачем?" is a question about the results and goals of an action. This is a question about the future. The question "Зачем?" can have different forms: it can sound like "For what purpose?", "For what?" "What should be the result?"
2. The question "Почему?" is a question about the events and circumstances that preceded an action. This is a question about the past.

Sometimes people answer the question "Зачем?" the same way they answer question "Почему?":

- Зачем ты оставил документы на столе?
- Потому что мне нужно было срочно уйти.

This is not due to a misunderstanding of the question, but rather for psychological defense.

The question "Зачем?" is very useful. It helps one switch from the reasons for an action to its results, switches thoughts from the past to the future, and, in general, increases the awareness of words, thoughts and deeds.

Answer (score 1):

Разница смыслов в том, **что мы хотим услышать в ответ** на каждый из вопросов.

1. **"Зачем?"** мы спрашиваем, чтобы понять **результат** в будущем, **планы** на будущее

   [мы в настоящем спрашиваем "Зачем?"]--------->[результат в будущем]

Примеры:

- "**Зачем** ты меня позвал?" (= Что ты от меня хочешь? Какой результат ты хотел получить? Чем я могу быть тебе полезен?)
- "**Зачем** нам брать купальники в поездку?" (= Что мы будем делать с ними? Мы **планируем** искупаться)
- "**Зачем** люди покупают дорогие автомобили?" (= Какой желаемый результат от покупки дорогих автомобилей? Например, можно ответить: "чтобы быть заметными", "чтобы соседи завидовали", "чтобы было удобно ездить")

2. **"Почему?"** мы спрашиваем, чтобы узнать **причины** какого-то события, действия, поступка в прошлом или чтобы узнать **причины** в убеждениях, мнении, мотивах человека.

   [причина в прошлом или как результат убеждений человека]<-----[спрашиваем "Почему?"]

Причина в прошлом:

- "**Почему** ты меня позвал?" (= Что было причиной для тебя меня позвать? Что произошло, что ты решил меня позвать?)
- "**Почему** мы не взяли купальники в поездку?" (= По какой причине мы их не взяли? Катя собирала сумку и забыла их взять)

Причина в убеждениях, мнении, мотивах человека:

- "**Почему** люди покупают дорогие автомобили?" (= Что для людей является причиной желания купить дорогой автомобиль? Например, можно ответить "потому что видели рекламу", "потому что ценят удобство")

А ещё есть типичные ответы на эти вопросы. На вопрос "почему?" ответ обычно начинается с фраз "потому что...", "по причине того что...", из-за того что...". На вопрос "зачем?" мы обычно отвечаем фразами "для того чтобы...", "чтобы...".

Иногда люди на вопрос "зачем?", отвечают причинами, а на вопрос "почему?" отвечают планами. Мы так делаем, когда считаем, что это лучше объяснит нашу позицию или что из причины понятен сразу желаемый результат.

Пример:

- "Зачем вы сажаете картошку?" - "(Потому что) мы любим свои овощи".

  Человек намеренно рассказывает причину, потому что в контексте этого диалога причина (любовь к овощам) по его мнению содержит и ответ на вопрос "зачем?".

  По смыслу это равносильно ответу: "Для того чтобы вырастить собственные овощи, а не покупать в магазине".

Answer (score 0):

**Почему** refers to a “past” *why* — asking *why* when seeking a cause, like *Why is the sky blue?* Remember, the first letter, п, is like p in “past”.

**Зачем** is the “future” *why* — asking *why* when seeking a goal or purpose, like asking why someone has contacted you unexpectedly.

Answer (score -4):

i m not sure that it is analogue questions in english, but

Зачем used when asker had known, but for some reason the happening
doesn't coincide with his knowledge, or asker wants to know a reason or a case facts, sometimes it is a form of the command - you do wrong, listen to me. Зачем used for teaching and studying.

> -Зачем ты стоишь в луже?
> -А вот зачем! - отвечает [отвечает мальчик и...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SfbRVVvHcqk)

Почему - is more close to kids why, when they doesn't know about cases and reasons, because they doesn't understand ideas ans causes, but they asked "why, why, why?" Why-asker don't mean or know why another did something or how to asker need to understand this, почему mean "I have no any idea why, can you explain, what this mean?".

Why are you late?

> -Зачем ты опоздал? Будешь теперь в отстающих - you ll be with losers then.
>
> -Почему ты опоздал?(I don't know, tell me)

Почему ты говоришь по-русски? - it sounds comical or joking because the answer can be "Because I m Russian(don't you know this?)?..." In Russian *ты* mean that you know about thyself reasons, it is your close known person. It heard strange and looks that you don't recognize your close friend. But possible to ask: "Почему он говорит по-русски?" - because third person is possible to be unknown to you. So, почему used also when asker asking obvious(for all) question. *Уже полночь, почему мы еще не спим? Потому что завтра выходной!*

Or this example of [obvious почему](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r904totmVtk).

Почему is out of reason and sense. Reason will be tomorrow, tomorrow will be free day, but tonight is the time out of free/unfree stance - we do that we will.

Not all forms is possible:

> -Почему зимой холодно? Потому что день короче, солнце светит меньше, идёт снег...
> -А "зачем зимой холодно?" - не говорят. But, зачем зимой тепло? - is possible. Чтобы не замерзнуть, to not get freezed. And also possible "зачем зимой холод" - for what reason we need freez in cold winter?
>
> -Почему огонь горячий? Because burning particles have very hi termal energy.
>
> -Зачем огонь горячий? - не говорят, because fire is not cold, it is hot and it is normal.

Почему used in negative forms(of feelings or something out of control), and an respondent's answer is not necessary to be, because not a fact that he know why he did:

> -Почему ты забыл? Память дырявая (то есть он забыл, потому что он забывчивый).
>
> -Почему ты не хочешь? Не хочется.
>
> -Зачем ты забыл?-sounds strange, that someone can forget purposely. Don't know how to answer.
>
> -Зачем ты не хочешь - не говорят.

Зачем can imply that someone is doing wrong:

> -Зачем ты дразнишь собаку?(укусит, it ll bit you/don't do).

So, зачем can sign from: "I don't sure that you are right, why you do this?" - to - "you are wrong/don't do this/thou must do another way". That is why зачем  may sound rude, and you can get an answer "зачем - за диваном" means "It's not your case!". Почему hasn't a commanding tone, but почему-asker can look naive like a kid sometimes.

Почему-question is more universal, you don't need to know anything to ask this question. But почему-question is addressing to stance, or process, not to thing function(not about things), at that time зачем-question is about the functionality of something.